# Trouble with concatenating an array of 4 binary ints

Tags: python, concatenation, dice

just starting out in any type of programming and python is the language my into class is teaching in.

My teacher has a game she plays called binary dice and its just 4 die(representing a nibble), each die has 3 sides (0) and three sides (1), your supposed to arrange the die so that you get the highest possible value, then translate that value into a hex digit.

Well I'm trying to write that into a py program so it gens 4 binary digits, has user sort them, checks it, then has user input the hex value, checking it against its own binary-to-hex translation, using the concatenated nibble as one 4 digit value.

heres what i got so far... (again, only been programming for a couple weeks)

```
#Binary Dice Program

#individual integers generated randomly
print ("This Game Simulates Binary Dice,")
print ("Your objective is to sort the 4 given")
print ("binary numbers so they make the highest")
print ("possible hexadecimal value...")
auth = input("When you are ready, hit Enter to continue...")
print (" ")

#generation and display of given ints
import random
die0 = random.randint (0, 1)
die1 = random.randint (0, 1)
die2 = random.randint (0, 1)
die3 = random.randint (0, 1)
dieArray=[die0, die1, die2, die3]
print ("Your die are showing as ")
print (dieArray)

#sort array from highest to lowest
def get_data():
       return dieArray
nib=get_data()
nib.sort(reverse=True)

for num in nib:
    print .join((str(num))) #I think Im doing this completely wrong

#Once we get a concatenated 4 digit binary nibble,
#I want to be able to translate that nibble into a hex value
#that is used to check against the user's input
```

after the concatenation of the sorted numbers in the array

for instance if i get an array of [0,1,1,0] i want it to sort and concatenate to show as a new value, "1100"

Comment: to get hex value: `hex(int("1100", 2))`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian and just replace it so it looks like 'hex(int([name], 2))' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for instance if i get an array of [0,1,1,0] i want it to sort and concatentate to show as a new value, "1100"

```
L = [0,1,1,0]
print("1"*L.count(1) + "0"*L.count(0)) # O(n)
```

Or

```
L = [0,1,1,0]
print("".join(map(str, sorted(L, reverse=True)))) # O(n*log n)
```

You could roll all binary dices at once:

```
roll_n_dices = lambda n: random.getrandbits(n)
r = roll_n_dices(4)
binstr = bin(r)[2:].zfill(4)
sorted_binstr = "1"*binstr.count("1") + "0"*binstr.count("0")
hex_value = hex(int(sorted_binstr, 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to sort and join a list.  I would use the line of code

```
''.join(map(str, sorted(nib, reverse = True)))
```